# Forms disable/enable buttons script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button

I want to show tour packages on page. I put 3 tour packages but I will more tour packages. 
1. Tours  Start Res. button is disabled because I haven't selected Room number and Country.(its true)
But at the 2. and 3. Tour Start Res. Buttons are enable. These buttons should be shown disable status.

You should consider; I will add more tour package on page and these forms shouldn't affect each others. 
Please help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
  
 
  <style type='text/css'>
    
  </style>
  


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('#submitorder').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

function updateFormEnabled() {
    if (verifyAdSettings()) {
        $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', '');
    } else {
        $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}

function verifyAdSettings() {
    if ($('#ad_duration').val() != '' && $('#ad_type').val() != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

$('#ad_duration').change(updateFormEnabled);

$('#ad_type').change(updateFormEnabled);
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<b>1. Tour</b><br>
<br>

  <form id="ad_form" method="post" action="../../form/form4.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="Code" value="TP5RMI1" />
    <p>
        <select id="ad_type" name="ad_type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Room number</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>
        <label for="ad_type" class="labelStrong">How many room(s) do you need?</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="ad_duration" name="ad_duration">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
            <option value="GR">Germany</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="EN">England</option>
        </select>
        <label for="ad_duration" class="labelStrong">Where are coming?</label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Reservation" id="submitorder" />
    </p>
</form><br><br>
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________<br>
<br>

<b>2. Tour</b><br>
<br>

  <form id="ad_form" method="post" action="../../form/form4.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="Code" value="TP5RMI2" />
    <p>
        <select id="ad_type" name="ad_type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Room number</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>
        <label for="ad_type" class="labelStrong">How many room(s) do you need?</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="ad_duration" name="ad_duration">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
            <option value="GR">Germany</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="EN">England</option>
        </select>
        <label for="ad_duration" class="labelStrong">Where are coming?</label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Reservation" id="submitorder" />
    </p>
</form><br><br>
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________<br>
<br>

<b>3. Tour</b><br>
<br>

  <form id="ad_form" method="post" action="../../form/form4.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="Code" value="TP5RMI3" />
    <p>
        <select id="ad_type" name="ad_type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Room number</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>
        <label for="ad_type" class="labelStrong">How many room(s) do you need?</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="ad_duration" name="ad_duration">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
            <option value="GR">Germany</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="EN">England</option>
        </select>
        <label for="ad_duration" class="labelStrong">Where are coming?</label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Reservation" id="submitorder" />
    </p>
</form><br><br>

   
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same ID. You **should not** have multiple elements with the same IDs on the page. Either have different IDs or if you want to act them in a certain manner, have a same class name for them. But don't use same ID across various elements.

Use different IDs for the three buttons and it would work. Initially have them all disabled in your html and then enable them in jQuery code. Something like,

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Reservation" id="submitorder1" disabled/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Reservation" id="submitorder2" disabled/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Reservation" id="submitorder3" disabled/>
```

Then enable them if the conditions are satisfied as,

`$('#submitorder1').attr('disabled', '');` or `$('#submitorder2').attr('disabled', '');` and so on.

Comment: I didn get you? Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to find out how to use them? I shall provide the changes in sometime

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('#submitorder').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

function updateFormEnabled() {
    if (verifyAdSettings()) {
        $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', '');
    } else {
        $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}

function verifyAdSettings() {
    if ($('#ad_duration').val() != '' && $('#ad_type').val() != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

$('#ad_duration').change(updateFormEnabled);

$('#ad_type').change(updateFormEnabled);
});//]]>  

</script>